# What does cloud instance owned means?

Tags: sha256, websites, cloud-mining

I am using [this website](https://www.eobot.com/) for cloud mining cryptocurrency for free. I was reading about **How the Cloud Mining/Hashing Works** when I came to this point in which says

- (Cloud SHA-256) SHA-256 algorithm, 1.0 GHS per 1.0 cloud instance owned.
- (Cloud Scrypt) Scrypt algorithm, 1.0 MHS per 1.0 cloud instance owned.

Could you explain these points in an easy way so I can understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that for each cloud instance you own, you will get exactly 1 GHS or exactly 1 MHS, depending which type of cloud instance you own (sha256 or scrypt).